# Function not finding variable even though it is being passed in

Tags: python, function, variables

So when I run this code I get this error message and I'm not sure why, any help would be much appreciated.
This code is validating the what is entered into the entry box tho make sure that there is something in it and that the something in it is an integer, so that query in full program which this section is from can run without crashing

This is the error message:

```
Please enter a min number
Please enter a max number
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: getting_Prices_High() missing 1 required positional argument: 'maxPrice'
```

It will do this for either functions, the code is below

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk

    root = Tk()
    root.title('Mtb Encylopedia')
    root.geometry("1000x800")
    maxPrice = []
    minPrice = []

    def getting_Prices_Low(minPrice):
        val1 = 0
        try:
            val1 = (int(priceEntryBox2.get()))
            minPrice.append(val1)
        except:
            print("Please enter a min number")
        return(minPrice)

    def getting_Prices_High(maxPrice):
        val2= 0
        try:
            val2 = (int(priceEntryBox1.get()))
            maxPrice.append(val2)
        except:
            print("Please enter a max number")
        return(maxPrice)

    priceEntryBox1 = Entry(root, width=50)
    priceEntryBox1.grid(row=6, column=4)

    priceEntryBox2 = Entry(root, width=50)
    priceEntryBox2.grid(row=6, column=3)

    myButtonLow = Button(root, text="Enter Min", command=getting_Prices_Low)
    myButtonLow.grid(row=7, column=3)

    myButtonHigh = Button(root, text="Enter Max", command=getting_Prices_High)
    myButtonHigh.grid(row=7, column=4)

    minPrice = getting_Prices_Low(minPrice)
    maxPrice = getting_Prices_High(maxPrice)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you think is the value of `maxPrice` when you click on the button?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass maxPrice but instead of:

```
Button(window, text="Bla Bla", command=my_function(arg))
```

You need to do:

```
Button(window, text="Bla Bla", command=lambda: my_function(arg))
```

since if you do example 1 "my_function" will immediately be executed and the return of my_function will be used as the command.

Comment: What does the lambda do? Just so I can understand my code going forward.

Comment: Please take a look at [this](https://realpython.com/python-lambda/#anonymous-functions)

Comment: Also how could I check that it is getting minPrice at the end as if I print minPrice below minPrice = getting_Prices_Low(minPrice) it just prints the empty array that was setup at the start?

Comment: Button callbacks are not called with any arguments. `command`, then, must be a function with no parameters.

Comment: Thanks for that @DerSchinken that seems to have fixed my problem for now

Comment: @chepner Ik but it's an error I've seen a lot so I included it as an example of how to not do it

Comment: @DerSchinken any idea why when I pass out maxPrice or minPrice the value seems to go back to 0?